# Ambiguous reference to member in Xcode 8.2.1

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I've just managed to setup SwiftyBeaver logging framework for my Xcode project, it works fine but Xcode raises an error every time I call my logging framework (that does **not** prevent me to compile **nor** to log properly though).

[image: 1]

What I've done is just declaring my logging variable outside of a class' scope with some configurations like below:

```html
let log = SwiftyBeaver.self

#if DEBUG
    let logMinLevel = SwiftyBeaver.Level.debug
    let logFormat = "$DHH:mm:ss.SSS$d $C$L$c $N.$F:$l - $M"
#else
    let logMinLevel = SwiftyBeaver.Level.warning
    let logFormat = "$DHH:mm:ss.SSS$d $C$L$c - $M"
#endif
```

Is there any way to get rid of that error message?

Comment: If it is inside a closure, use `self.log...`

Comment: @shallowThought I won't be able to do that since `log` is not a member of any class

Comment: @EricAya Same problem after renaming my variable to `logg`

Comment: @Slowbro I see. It's defined globally. In this case I wonder why the error says `member`

Comment: @shallowThought Yeah this is super weird

Comment: If it's not in a class, why is it annotated with the `internal` ACL? Serious question - I'm confused about this.

Comment: @EricAya Since I'm developing a framework I wanted to make sure that it won't be accessible outside of the framework itself. Is it not needed to do that? Same problem after removing `internal` though.

Comment: Anything that is not explicitly "public" or "open" is not visible outside the module, no need for the "internal" annotation here... if it's in a class. I've never seen such an annotation used outside of a class (this doesn't mean it's wrong - it's just very unusual).

Comment: Weird that you can build with errors.

Comment: @shallowThought I'm pretty sure there are no errors and this is juste some UI bug.

Comment: @EricAya thanks for the explanations, I updated the snippet and my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue disappeared.

After reporting it I changed my IDE for AppCode, then I came back to Xcode recently and the problem is no longer here.